# How to determine an index of first redundant parenthesis in arethmetic expression?

Tags: java, arrays, string

for example: 
if an input is (5*x) the return result is:
"Parentheses are placed correctly"

if an input is (((5*x) the return result is:
"Parentheses are placed incorrectly"
"Quantity of redundant opening parenthesis: 3"

if an input is (5*x)+10*y)+5*z) my return result must be:
"Parentheses are placed incorrectly"
"Index of first redundant closing parenthesis: 10" – This is what I can not understand how to do.................

How to implement an output, that shows an index of first redundant closing parenthesis?

This is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter an arithmetic expression:");

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String arithmeticExpression = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println(parenthesesCheckup(arithmeticExpression));

    }

    public static String parenthesesCheckup(String arithmeticExpression) {

        char openingParenthesis = '(';
        char closingParenthesis = ')';

        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();

        char array[] = arithmeticExpression.toCharArray();

        for (char current : array) {
            if ((current == closingParenthesis) && stack.empty()) {
                stack.push(current);
                char previousStack = stack.peek();
                switch (current) {
                    case ')':
                        if (previousStack == '(')
                    stack.pop();
                    return "Parentheses are placed incorrectly\n" +
                            "Index of first redundant closing parenthesis: ";
                }
            }

            if (current == openingParenthesis) {
                stack.push(current);
            }

            if ((current == closingParenthesis) && !stack.empty()) {
                char previousStack = stack.peek();
                switch (current) {
                    case ')':
                        if (previousStack == '(')
                            stack.pop();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (stack.empty()) {
            return "Parentheses are placed correctly";
        } else {
            return "Parentheses are placed incorrectly\n" +
                    "Quantity of redundant opening parenthesis: " + stack.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is expected for such input: `5+3)+(2+1` ?

Comment: This looks like a "please do my homework for me" question.  Please consider this guide to writing a good question on SO: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: @SergeyS, such input is not expected :)

Comment: @JoeC, Ok. First experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to implement an output, that shows an index of first redundant closing parenthesis?

Add a counter for the character indexes that you have processed.
For example you could convert the for-each loop to a counting loop:

```
for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    char current = array[index];
    // ...
```

And then when you found an out of place closing parenthesis, append the current index to your string:

```
    return "Parentheses are placed incorrectly\n" +
            "Index of first redundant closing parenthesis: " + index;
```